# Frequently call "tableView.reloadData" in GCD main threat get crash error "Index out of range"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous, reloaddata

Sorry, I'm beginner to learn IOS.
I have a problem about my tableView and reload data.
When I frequently call "getData", I will crash and get error.
But I don't know where my data make it crash.
I guess I first call reloadData, and then the list.count are already changed in global thread 
Have any advice to avoid it?
Thanks.

Crash Log:

```
fatal error: Index out of range
```

Model:

```
class ChatroomList:Model {

    var all:[Chatroom] {
    var rooms:[Chatroom] = [Chatroom]()
    self.chatrooms.forEach({ (id,chatroom) in
        if showType.contains(chatroom.type) {
            rooms.append(chatroom)
        }
    })
    return rooms
    }
}
```

ViewController:

```
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift
import Alamofire

class ListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {                     

    let chatrooms:ChatroomList = ChatroomList()
    var list:[Chatroom] = [Chatroom]()
    var subscribe:Disposable?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        subscribe = rooms.notifySubject.subscribe({ json in
                self.getData() //here is called frequently 
        })
        self.getData()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        subscribe?.dispose()
    }

    func getData() {

        var idList:[String] = []

        self.list.removeAll()
        self.list = chatrooms.all

        guard self.list.isEmpty == false else {
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.global().async() {

            self.list.sort(by: { (a,b) in
                if a.message.datetime.isEmpty {
                    return false
                }

            return a.message.datetime > b.message.datetime
            })

            self.list = self.list.filter { (chatroom) -> Bool in
                if chatroom.id.isEmpty {
                    return true
                }
                if idList.contains(chatroom.id) {
                    return false
                }
                idList.append(chatroom.id)
                return true
            }   

            DispatchQueue.main.sync() {

                self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
      }
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return list.count
}

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if list[indexPath.row].type == .city {

        let cell: ChatroomCityTableViewCell = ChatroomCityTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

        cell.loadByCityChatroom(chatroom: list[indexPath.row], cityId: list[indexPath.row].cityId)

        return cell
    }else{

        let cell: ChatroomTableViewCell = ChatroomTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.loadByChatroom(chatroom: list[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to move your main queue closure inside the global queue brackets. Also I think you should make that global queue async

Comment: but Is tableView.reloadDate legal in global queue?

Comment: try with DispatchQueue.global().async()

Comment: @Beginnerrrrrr you should call reloadData inside the main.async{}, but the main.async should be inside global.async

Comment: @Woof But I already write inside global queue.

Comment: @Beginnerrrrrr show me please your new code you've edited

Comment: @ReinierMelian I try but I want the "list" filter ending then sort. Async also can do that?

Comment: Yes! Just call main.async after filtering

Comment: try with DispatchQueue.global().async() instead and let me know, must work!

Comment: Thanks All, But the crash  also happen.

Comment: Is My model ChatroomList number wrong?

Comment: or filter array wrong?

Comment: 1. "When I frequently call "getData", I will crash and get error." <-- do you mean if you make the go in an out of the view very quickly? 2. Is this viewController inside a tabBarController or its inside a navigagtionController?

Comment: 1.yes 2.yes,tabbar with navigation. Does it have relation?

Comment: I found my "list" data will append again, so it's count to be 0. I think it's reason.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely caused by how you currently use the GCD (Grand central dispatch).

When reloading, the tableView will ask many different questions like the number of rows and the cells for each of these rows. If the data changes between one of these calls it will result in an inconsistency exception because it tried to add or remove a number of row that no longer represents the data.

Reloading the tableView asynchronously on the main thread while your getData function can change the list at any given time will result in the above error.

The solution is not simple, you need to rethink how to update the list so it won't change while the tableView reload its data.

One thing you could try is to do something like:

```
func getData() {
    // You cannot clear or change self.list here

    guard !chatrooms.all.isEmpty else { return }

    DispatchQueue.global().async() {
         let updatedData = process(newData: self.chatrooms.all)

         DispatchQueue.main.sync() {
             self.list = updatedData
             self.tableView.reloadData()
         }
    }
}

private func process(newData data: [Chatroom]) -> [Chatroom] {
    // Do all your logic without making any changes to self.list
}
```

The key is to never make any change to the data that is used when reloading the tableView except synchronously on the main thread juste before reloading.

Comment: sorry @Kedio, The crash also happen.

Comment: @Beginnerrrrrr it may not be what you want, but for debugging purposes: Can you remove DispatchQueue calls altogether to see if you get the expected result without the crash?

Comment: I try but it will very slow to use app, because sort&filter data.

Comment: @Beginnerrrrrr I have updated my answer. If this does not work you will have to use semaphore/mutex to prevent modifying the data when it shouldn't be. But this can get messy and is hard to maintain.